# Sitecore Solr search indexing getting stopped

Tags: solr, indexing

We are seeing Solr master and web index updates are getting stopped randomly in mid of the day. I tried one approach that is mentioned in this [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2117/58).

- Updated the master index strategy to use `IntervalAsynchronous` strategy and `CheckForThreshold` to *False*
- Updated the web index strategy that we are using `OnPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance` to have the `CheckForThreshold` to *False*.

We are still seeing the Solr index updates getting stopped. Any updates to the master items or publishing the items to the web are not triggering the index updates. We have the `SwitchOnRebuild` indexes in place for the Solr indexes. Can anyone provide more ways to troubleshoot/fix this?

[image]

We are using the Sitecore 9.1.1 version and Solr cloud for our infrastructure.
We also have separate Coveo indexes on the same setup.

Comment: Are you doing bulk publishing?

Comment: There is a sitecron job runs every hour to do smartpublish of the site to web.

Comment: It means publishing queue got stuck. Can you please try publishing manually and verify index..

Comment: No, I tried publishing manually .. it won't reindex. Rebuilding web index from the indexing manager quickly quits in few seconds.

Comment: Any specific error in log..

Comment: @RamakrishnaKudikala: Did you figure out the resolution? We have started to notice similar behavior in our Coveo Master Index.